# java.io.FileNotFoundException(Access denied)

Tags: java, ftp, glassfish

When I deploy ear project to glassfish, project deployed normaly and start and work. But in glassfish log i see this stacktrace:

```
 [2015-11-04T18:20:36.297+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1446639636297] [levelValue: 900] [[
  PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/ejb/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\generated\ejb\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (Access denied)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:445)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:697)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6031)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5929)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
[2015-11-04T18:20:36.310+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1446639636310] [levelValue: 900] [[
  PWC6351: In TLD scanning, the supplied resource file:/C:/app/svnApp/branches/QCforCCMaven/ear/target/ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\app\svnApp\branches\QCforCCMaven\ear\target\ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT\jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar (Не удается найти указанный файл)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:109)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJar(TldScanner.java:445)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:697)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.scanTlds(TldScanner.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TldScanner.onStartup(TldScanner.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:6031)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5929)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

And when i tried get files from FTP(i use `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`)
my server is freezes. I thing it is connected. what could be the problem?